# Remove repetitive and sorting value with awk

Tags: awk

the input.txt

```
51711    773.00    231.001    8   121    232.00    772.00    776.001
51711    773.00    231.001   17   241    226.00    769.00    776.001
51711    773.00    231.001   30   411    220.00    765.00    776.001
51711    773.00    231.001   43   581    214.00    761.00    776.001
51711    773.00    231.001   66   861    208.00    756.00    776.001
51711    773.00    231.001   91  2231    202.00    749.00    751.001
51811    773.00    230.001    8   121    232.00    772.00    776.001
51811    773.00    230.001   17   241    226.00    769.00    776.001
51811    773.00    230.001   30   411    220.00    765.00    776.001
51811    773.00    230.001   43   581    214.00    761.00    776.001
51811    773.00    230.001   66   861    208.00    756.00    776.001
51811    773.00    230.001   91  2231    202.00    749.00    751.001
51911    772.00    229.001    8   121    232.00    772.00    776.001
51911    772.00    229.001   17   241    226.00    769.00    776.001
51911    772.00    229.001   30   411    220.00    765.00    776.001
51911    772.00    229.001   43   581    214.00    761.00    776.001
51911    772.00    229.001   66   861    208.00    756.00    776.001
51911    772.00    229.001   91  2231    202.00    749.00    751.001
```

Let assume that the input have a long list (input have been trimmed) and I wonder if we could count repetitive and output sorted value with only "awk"

```
awk '$1>=51711 && $1<=51911 && $5<=2231  {a[$4,$5,$6,$7,$8]++}END{for(i in a){print a[i],i}}' input.txt
```

So I tried using this command (from https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/145005-awk-count-duplicated-lines.html), but the output isn't as expected

```
3 66861208.00756.00776.001
3 17241226.00769.00776.001
3 43581214.00761.00776.001
3 912231202.00749.00751.001
3 30411220.00765.00776.001
3 8121232.00772.00776.001
```

This one-liner succeeded, and I wish I could use with only using awk. Let me know your thought on this.

```
awk '$1>=51711 && $1<=51911 && $5<=2231 {print $4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' input.txt  | sort -k1n -k2n | uniq -c | awk '{printf "%10d %6d %6d %8.2f %8.2f %8.3f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
```

Expected output

```
         3      8    121   232.00   772.00  776.001
         3     17    241   226.00   769.00  776.001
         3     30    411   220.00   765.00  776.001
         3     43    581   214.00   761.00  776.001
         3     66    861   208.00   756.00  776.001
         3     91   2231   202.00   749.00  751.001
```

Comment: You check column 2 for values in the range 51711 to 51911, but all the values in column 2 in your input is in the 770's... did you mean to look at column 1 instead? Similar thing for column 6 looking like you meant to check column 5.

Comment: You also reference a column 9 but your data only has 8 columns...

Comment: actually, I've shoved some column, I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following(tested on your samples).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  SUBSEP=OFS
}
!b[$4,$5,$6,$7,$8]++{
  c[++count]=$4 OFS $5 OFS $6 OFS $7 OFS $8
}
{
  a[$4,$5,$6,$7,$8]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print a[c[i]],c[i]
  }
}
'    Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                                             ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                                            ##Starting BEGIN section here.
  SUBSEP=OFS                                      ##Setting SUBSEP to OFS(output field separator) as space for making array index separator.
}                                                 ##Closing BEGIN block here.
!b[$4,$5,$6,$7,$8]++{                             ##Checking condition if $4,$5,$6,$7,$8 index is NOT present in array b if yes then do following.
  c[++count]=$4 OFS $5 OFS $6 OFS $7 OFS $8       ##Creating an array c whose index is variable count and value is $4,$5,$6,$7,$8 of current line.
}
{
  a[$4,$5,$6,$7,$8]++                             ##Creating an array a whose index is $4,$5,$6,$7,$8 and keep increment its value whenever an occurenece comes.
}
END{                                              ##Mentioning END block of this code now.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){                          ##Starting a for loop from value i=1 to till value of count here.
    print a[c[i]],c[i]                            ##Printing value of array a whose index is array c with index i and printing array c with index i here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @user10254032, sure, you could up-vote answers too for encouraging people :)

Comment: I tried but "Votes cast by those with less than 15",